# Replace new line in a particular field in unix

Tags: unix, replace, find

I have a field in a file which has "\n" in between the value. I want to remove them. How can I do it?

For example, my 4th field may have one or more \n in them. I want to get rid of all of them.

```
a|b|c|d\nD\n\n|e
a1|b1|c1|d1\n\nd2\n|e1
```

Comment: do you mean the literal string `\n` or a new-line char, embedded in a field? please edit your Q to clarify. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using sed

With this as your test file:

```
$ cat file
a|b|c|d\nD\n\n|e
a1|b1|c1|d1\n\nd2\n|e1
```

The `\n` can be removed as follows:

```
$ sed 's|\\n||g' file
a|b|c|dD|e
a1|b1|c1|d1d2|e1
```

Or, to change the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak 's|\\n||g' file
```

This uses a single *substitute* command.  Substitution commands have the form `s|old|new|`.  In our case, `old` is `\n` except that sed interprets `\` as an escape character.  So, we have to double it to get a literal slash.  The replacement text, the `new` part, is nothing.  In sed, the command `s|\\n||`  would replace the first `\n` found with nothing.  Since you want to replace all such occurrences, we add `g` to the end of the substitute command: this tells sed to made the change globally.

#### Using awk

To replace backslash-n from the fourth field and only the fourth field:

```
$ awk -F\| '{gsub(/\\n/, "", $4); print}' OFS=\| file
a|b|c|dD|e
a1|b1|c1|d1d2|e1
```

To change the file in-place:

```
gawk -i inplace -F\| '{gsub(/\\n/, "", $4); print}' OFS=\| file
```

How it works:

- `-F\|`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator on input.
- `gsub(/\\n/, "", $4)`

  This tells awk to replace backslash-n with nothing wherever it occurs in field 4.
- `print`

  This tells awk to print the line.
- `OFS=\|`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator on output.

Comment: But I want to replace the \n only in the 4th field.. the ones at the end of the line must remain intact. if i use the above command, will it not replace the \n at the end of the lines too?

Comment: _"will it not replace the \n at the end of the lines too?"_  If you are referring to newline characters, then _no_, it will not.  It is only removing the character combinations backslash-n.  The two are different.